# Why is Clang crashing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang, clang++, llvm-clang

I built Cmake using `cmake -G"Visual Studio 12 2013" -T"LLVM-vs2013" ..`
But I have a weird problem with compiling libCinder. Clang keeps crashing, I'm wondering what's going on. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10.

Here is the Clang crash message:

```
1>Assertion failed: Content.size() != 0, file C:\src\llvm_package_325576\llvm\tools\clang\lib\AST\CommentParser.cpp, line 561
1>Wrote crash dump file "C:\Users\CLARKF~2\AppData\Local\Temp\CL.exe-4b17a8.dmp"
1>0x023F9208 (0x00000016 0x05401A08 0x75977340 0x00000003)
1>0x75903472 (0x05401B74 0x05401A08 0x0658C920 0x0658C5D8), abort() + 0x32 bytes(s)
1>0x75904D87 (0x00000231 0x0658C6A0 0x0658C908 0x0658C5E8), _get_wpgmptr() + 0x1777 bytes(s)
1>0x759041EB (0x00000231 0x03E75A6A 0x0658C920 0x03E75A6A), _get_wpgmptr() + 0xBDB bytes(s)
1>0x75904E86 (0x05401B74 0x05401A08 0x00000231 0x0658C600), _wassert() + 0x16 bytes(s)
1>0x03E75A6A (0x0658C9C0 0x000148F8 0x088B6F28 0x04434C13)
1>0x025AD53C (0x088B6F28 0x0000067B 0x0658C9CC 0x0E88F711)
1>0x02411564 (0x088BED78 0x04434C67 0x00000000 0x025AD4C9)
1>clang-cl.exe : error : clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
1>clang version 7.0.0 (trunk)
1>Target: i686-pc-windows-msvc
1>Thread model: posix
1>InstalledDir: C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\msbuild-bin
1>clang-cl.exe: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to https://bugs.llvm.org/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
1>clang-cl.exe: note: diagnostic msg:
1>********************
1>
1>PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
1>Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
1>clang-cl.exe: note: diagnostic msg: C:\Users\CLARKF~2\AppData\Local\Temp\ConvexHull-06cb76.cpp
1>clang-cl.exe: note: diagnostic msg: C:\Users\CLARKF~2\AppData\Local\Temp\ConvexHull-06cb76.sh
1>clang-cl.exe: note: diagnostic msg:
1>
1>********************
1>Done building project "cinder.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
2>------ Skipped Build: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
```

If anyone tell me why Clang would be failing, I would appreciate it alot.

Thanks,

Tre'

Comment: Can you add a small example of code that would make Clang crash ?

Comment: I have no clue as to what part of the code is making it crash to be honest. It seems to be crashing in between compiling files. However, I can say that I am linking PawLIB, cpgf, and libCinder. Though I don't know if that helps any.

Comment: Report the crash to the clang/llvm bug tracker as instructed.

Comment: Ok I will, thanks for the input!